# How do I join 2 tables but only grab max values from one of the tables I'm joining?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to perform a join on 2 tables while only grabbing the max from one of the columns of the table I'm joining with. I'm doing this in MSSQL.

So far I have the following statement that isn't working properly:

```
select 
u.Id, u.Date, p.Purchase_Date, p.Return_Date, p.Grade 
from Users u 
inner join (select _p.Id, _p.Purchase_Date, _p.Return_Date, max(_p.Sequence), _p.Grade from Purchases _p group by _p.Id, _p.Purchase_Date, _p.Return_Date, _p.Grade) p 
on (p.Id = u.Id) and u.Date between p.Purchase_Date and p.Return_Date
```

**Users table:**

```
Id        Date
--------------------
1        2018-10-29
2        2018-10-30
3        2018-03-23
```

**Purchases table:**

```
Id     Purchase_Date     Return_Date     Sequence     Grade
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1       2018-10-29        2018-11-02        3          88
1       2017-08-05        2017-09-02        1          91
1       2017-09-08        2017-10-11        2          35
2       2018-09-09        2018-11-11        2          68
2       2018-05-06        2018-08-15        1          70
3       2018-01-10        2018-01-30        1          55 
3       2018-02-28        2018-03-28        2          83
```

I would like my **results** to look like the following:

```
Id          Date        Purchase_Date       Return_Date       Grade    
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1        2018-10-29      2018-10-29          2018-11-02        88 
2        2018-10-30      2018-09-09          2018-11-11        68
3        2018-03-23      2018-02-28          2018-03-28        83
```

The query currently isn't returning the max values from the Sequence column properly and I'm getting duplicate records which is what I don't want.  i'm suspecting I'm using the max operator incorrectly or I could be joining this in a different way

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method, I think, uses `apply`:

```
select u.*, p.*
from users u cross apply
     (select top (1) p.*
      from purchases p
      where p.Id = u.Id and
            u.Date between p.Purchase_Date and p.Return_Date
      order by p.Purchase_Date desc
     ) p;
```